# android handle activity methods in another class

Tags: android, android-activity

I've an activity , I create another class in this activity :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newadd);

        new MahaleDialog(NewAdd.this);
    }
```

this is my class :

```
public class MahaleDialog implements View.OnClickListener,
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

 public MahaleDialog(final Activity act){
        this.act = act;
}
```

I've lots of code in my class, I want to use map in it , the question is ,I need to access methods in activity but I need to handle them in this class.

for example , I want to handle onStart or onBackPress in this class .

how can I do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create reference of inner class and call it like this..

```
public class NewAdd extends Activity {

    private MahaleDialog mDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newadd);
        mDialog = new MahaleDialog(NewAdd.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mDialog.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        mDialog.onBackPressed();
    }

    public class MahaleDialog implements View.OnClickListener {
        NewAdd act;

        MahaleDialog(final NewAdd act) {
            this.act = act;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }

        void onStart() {
            // your code for onStart
        }

        void onBackPressed() {
            act.onBackPressed(); // work like super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `MahaleDialog`:

```
((NewAdd)act).the_method_you_want();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the instance of your `class` on those events in the `Activity` class.

For example: suppose you initialize your class in the `onCreate` of the activity, and you have the corresponding methods written in your class,

```
onStart(){
  md.yourMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if that class is inside activity, you can access that activity simply by `Activity_name.this`

Answer (score 0):

To access your activity method you simply have to cast it in the class you want to use:

```
this.act = (YourActivityName) act;
```